# Creating custom sizeof() that returns narrower types

Tags: c++, templates

### The Issue

`sizeof` returns `size_t` type, so when passed as argument to functions that takes in narrower types (e.g. `unsigned char`), implicit conversion occurs. In many cases these are 3rd party library functions, so their prototypes are beyond my control. Compilers are now typically smart enough to detect whether such conversions would really cause truncation and warn you about it, but some static code analyzers will still flag such cases out, leading to lots of false positives. Explicitly casting the result of `sizeof` typically resolves the analysis warnings but it would hide the compiler warnings, not to mention that it makes things clunky.

### My Solution

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2>
struct sizeofxx {
    static constexpr T2 value{ sizeof(T1) };
};

template <class T>
constexpr unsigned int sizeof32 = sizeofxx<T, unsigned int>::value;

template <class T>
constexpr unsigned short sizeof16 = sizeofxx<T, unsigned short>::value;

template <class T>
constexpr unsigned char sizeof8 = sizeofxx<T, unsigned char>::value;
```

Usage:

```cpp
unsigned int foo = sizeof32<float>;
const char bar[255];
unsigned char foo3 = sizeof8<decltype(bar)>;
```

It relies on aggregate initialization to guard against narrowing conversion at compile time. So if I had used `bar[256]`, the build fails.

### Limitation

But as you can see, using it on variables is rather clunky (due to the need for `decltype`). Is there a simpler way to do this? I know one way is wrap it in a macro, but this would prevent IDEs like Visual Studio from helping you resolve the value when you mouseover it. Another way is to create a `constexpr` function:

```cpp
template <class T1>
constexpr unsigned char sizeof8f(T1&) {
    return sizeof(T1);
}
```

But this also does not allow for IDE code-time resolution, and would expand the number of symbols involved since they need to be of different names from the earlier implementation that operates on types.

Any other suggestions on resolving the root issue (static code analysis warnings) are welcomed. And no, suppressing them is not feasible.

Comment: I believe compiler would not generate call to the function. And you may want to use `const T&` or `T&&` so it can bind to rvalue.

Comment: I only rarely run into this as an issue.  My usual approach is to use `safe_cast` to the desired type, which ensure the domain can handle mapping to the range, otherwise trips an `assert`.  In a debug build; silent no-op in a release build (just an inline `static_cast`).  The `safe_cast` is a home grown C++ thing, not the C++/CLI one.

Comment: Why do you think `constexpr` functions would be called at runtime?

Comment: So what you are saying is you have functions that need the size of a datatype, but do not have a std::size_t as argument type? What about a creating a function style narrow_cast<target_t>(const std::size_t) that will throw if std::size_t is too large for the target type. So you can make those calls something like `Func(narrowing_cast<unsigned char>(sizeof(bar))`?

Comment: @Eljay I think we're trying to say the same thing.  But I rather fail fast then fail silently (a cast that has a domain error may still result in undesired behavior).

Comment: I wouldn't use an exception, because it is a runtime mechanism. A lossy narrowing conversion of a compile-time constant should be detected (and rejected) at compile time.

Comment: Passing uint8_t, uint16_t and even uint32_t (on 64bit arch) makes the code slower as the compiler will often have to 0-extend the value. It also means you have to template all your functions that take a size_t so they can adjust to different size types. It will be easy to get duplicate code for uint8_t, uint16_t and uint32_t size. You probably don't have that many cases with 64bit sizes but some people do. So potentially you end up with 4 times the amount of code leading to worse cache utilization. All for the sake of making passing the size more expensive, it's not saving registers in calls.

Comment: If you have a size just use `std::size_t`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I initially thought it would be inlined too until I saw the assembly output. I've amended my post to with a gotbolt sample to demonstrate this.

Comment: Enable optimization or replace `constexpr` with `consteval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific problem, there need not be any runtime checks even on debug builds as some has suggested, since the value is itself a `constexpr`. You can write a simple utility to cast a value to the smallest type that is able to hold it.

```
template<size_t N>
inline constexpr auto minuint = []{
    if constexpr(N >= 1ull << 32)
        return N;
    else if constexpr(N >= 1ull << 16)
        return uint32_t(N);
    else if constexpr(N >= 1ull << 8)
        return uint16_t(N);
    else
        return uint8_t(N);
}();
```

On the other hand, no function or template can ever accept both expressions and types.
The only possible way to imitate `sizeof` behaviour is to use a macro.

```
#define Sizeof(x) minuint<sizeof(x)>
```

With this, you never get false warnings on narrowing conversions: if there is a warning, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It uses only a single symbol so it's a lot more user friendly than my solution. Looks like the macro (at the expense of losing IDE's code-time resolution) is an unavoidable tradeoff if I want less clunkiness. Just curious, any specific reason why the limit values are built manually instead of using std::numeric_limits?

Comment: @wmjdgla Short answer: no. Long answer: there's something (not that consequential) to be said for doing it either way. This is probably better for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler would most likely optimize out the function, even without `constexpr` [example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7KfPYxsoY)

---

you may want to use `T&&` or `const T&` so it bind to an rvalue, depend on what you want.

```cpp
template<typename size_type,typename T>
constexpr size_type sizeofxx(T&& t){
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
template<typename size_type, typename object_type>
constexpr size_type
sizeof_as(object_type& object) {
    // TODO: static_assert(...)
    return size_type{sizeof object};
}

auto foo = ...; // some object
auto size = sizeof_as<uint8_t>(foo);
```

First template parameter is given explicitly, second one deduced from the argument.

Maybe add to that another function that doesn't require an object but just its type, similar to the second `sizeof` syntax:

```
template<typename size_type, typename object_type>
constexpr size_type
sizeof_as() {
    // TODO: static_assert(...)
    return size_type{sizeof (object_type)};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passer By's solution requires at least C++17 to work and it just occurred to me that a C++11 solution is also possible. The approach is to use SFINAE to let the compiler pick the appropriate function overload for every invocation:

```cpp
template<size_t S, std::enable_if_t<S <= 0xFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr auto mintype() { return (uint8_t)S; }

template<size_t S, std::enable_if_t<0xFFull < S && S <= 0xFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr auto mintype() { return (uint16_t)S; }

template<size_t S, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFull < S && S <= 0xFFFFFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr auto mintype() { return (uint32_t)S; }

template<size_t S, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFFFFFull < S, int> = 0>
constexpr auto mintype() { return S; }

#define sizeofex(S) mintype<sizeof(S)>()
```

Still, it requires a macro for ease of use. We can avoid the macro by tweaking the implementation a bit, at the cost of doubling the code required:

```cpp
// Overloads for variables
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) <= 0xFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint8_t sizeofex(const T&) { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFull < sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) <= 0xFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint16_t sizeofex(const T&) { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFull < sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) <= 0xFFFFFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint32_t sizeofex(const T&) { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFFFFFull < sizeof(T), int> = 0>
constexpr uint64_t sizeofex(const T&) { return sizeof(T); }

// Overloads for types
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) <= 0xFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint8_t sizeofex() { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFull < sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) <= 0xFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint16_t sizeofex() { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFull < sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) <= 0xFFFFFFFFull, int> = 0>
constexpr uint32_t sizeofex() { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<0xFFFFFFFFull < sizeof(T), int> = 0>
constexpr uint64_t sizeofex() { return sizeof(T); }

template<class T>
constexpr auto sizeoftype = sizeofex<T>(); // Optional, requires C++14
```

Usage:

```cpp
auto bar = sizeofex(var);
auto bar2 = sizeofex<type>();
auto bar3 = sizeoftype<type>; // Requires C++14
```

`sizeoftype` has the benefit of being resolvable by IDEs like Visual Studio when you mouse over it.